# How to load pop-up ad inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm implementing pop up ads for my site. The popup opens when clicked anywhere on the site except on iframe. Why does this happen? Sure iframe is separate from the entire website but why does it prevent a pop up from loading? Is there anyway to load pop-up ad inside an iframe i.e when someone press yt play button

Comment: Click events on iframe content is handled by that iframe content. As for your question, probably not. You need a way to capture the click but that means clicking on something you have control over. However, the techniques for doing that also prevent interaction with the iframe.

Comment: Please dont use iFrames https://www.designyourway.net/blog/misc/dangers-and-security-risks-of-using-iframes/

Use modals instead.

Comment: Do you control the page within the iframe? If it's a third-party site then you probably won't be able to do this (unless they've specifically provided a method for you using e.g. postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

YT will not allow anyone to use its play button with a event listener.
So, you have to make a `<div class="play"></div>` make its `position: absolute;` and `z-index: (any bigger value)` and then put it in front of the play button and then if anyone tries to click on paly button of your video he will click on the div which will show a ad and when some closes the ad then make `.play{ display: none;}` and now your div will be removed so the person would be able to click on the play button and see the video.